# Creating abstract method that returns different object depending from which implementation it was called

Tags: java

I have five classes that are extended from a superclass, I'll call it AbstractEntity class for example. Each entity has a set of entityData:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "entity1")
class Entity1 extends AbstractEntity{
  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "Entity1")
  private Set<EntityData1> data;
  ...
  public Set<EntityData1> getData()
  { return data; }
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "entity2")
class Entity2 extends AbstractEntity{
  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "Entity2")
  private Set<EntityData2> data;
  ...
    public Set<EntityData2> getData()
    { return data; }
}
```

Each EntityData in its turn is extended from AbstractData class.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "entity_data1")
class EntityData1 extends AbstractData{
    @ManyToOne(...)
    @JoinColumn(name = "entity1_ID")
    private Entity1 entity1;
    ...
}
```

Both Entity and EntityData are separate tables in DB, that is we have 5 tables for Entity1 to Entity5 and 5 tables for EntityData1 to EntityData5.

What we need is the ability to write a single method that can take any Entity object and call a getData() method from it and get the correct EntityData object in return. That is if you call getData() from Entity2 you would get EntityData2.
Right now if someone wants to create method that cycles through entityData objects to find something, then he has to write five separate methods with very similar code.

I tried to put the getData() method in the AbstractEntity class like so:

```
abstract class AbstractEntity{
  ...
    public abstract <T> Set<T> getData();
}
```

And then access the entityData object for example like so:

```
public static <T> T findPropertyByAlias(T entity){ 
    for (T entityData : entity.getData()) {
        do something
    }
    return entityData for appropriate Entity object.
}
```

But this obviously doesn't work.
Is there a practical way to get that getData() method into abstract class but to make it return appropriate entityData object?

Comment: do you mean a different type of Object?

Comment: I mean that if I call getData for example from object of type Wolf, I would get WolfData, but if I call it from object of type Sheep, I would get SheepData.

Comment: what is wrong with returning a `Set<? extends AbstractEntity>`?

Comment: @Turing85 he's not talking about the entities themselves, but about a member of them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The generics approach that you did is correct. However, it needs some modifications.

```
abstract class AbstractEntity <T extends AbstractData>{
    public abstract Set<T> getData();
}
```

Then you declare the entity implementation as follows:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "entity1")
class Entity1 extends AbstractEntity<EntityData1>{
  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "Entity1")
  private Set<EntityData1> data;

  public Set<EntityData1> getData()
  { return data; }
}
```

---

```
public static <T extends AbstractData> T findPropertyByAlias(T entity){ 
    for (T entityData : entity.getData()) {
        do something
    }
    return entityData for appropriate Entity object.
}
```

Comment: I didn't know that you can write <T extends AbstractData>. I will try right now. Thanks.

Comment: I downvoted because  the `AbstractData` doesn't have the `getData` method

Comment: Looks like it works!
Only i changed that findPropertyByAlias() like so:
public static <T extends AbstractData> T findPropertyByAlias(AbstractEntity<T> entity)

Many thanks. You helped a lot. Got +1000XP for my Java skill also :)

Answer (score 1):

Introduce a generic param for the `AbstractEntity`:

```
interface AbstractData {}
abstract class AbstractEntity<DATA extends AbstractData> {
    public abstract Set<DATA> getData();
}
```

Each `Entity` decides which `AbstractData` implementation to use:

```
class Entity1 extends AbstractEntity<EntityData1> {
    ...
    @Override
    public Set<EntityData1> getData() { ... }
}
```

Each `EntityData` is an `AbstractData`:

```
class EntityData1 implements AbstractData {}
```

The method may look like:

```
public static <D extends AbstractData, T extends AbstractEntity<D>> Set<D> findPropertyByAlias(T entity) {
    for (D data : entity.getData()) { ... }
    return entity.getData();
}
```

I am returning a `Set<D>`, but you probably want an element of the collection. If so, change the return type to `D` and pick up the needed element to return.

Answer (score 0):

Considering your example (in the comments):

(One of) the easiest way(s):

1. Create a interface called 'Data'
2. Have all your classes, like WolfData and SheepData implement this interface
3. Set the returnType to Data.

This way, each implementation of Data (including WolfData and SheepData) are allowed as returnvalues.